# I have no idea Object(this) means

Tags: javascript

In https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

there is a line like

```
// Steps 1-2.
if (this == null) {
  throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
}

var O = Object(this);          // <- WHAT IS THIS???????????

// Steps 3-5.
var len = O.length >>> 0;

// Steps 6-7.
var start = arguments[1];
var relativeStart = start >> 0;

// Step 8.
var k = relativeStart < 0 ?
  Math.max(len + relativeStart, 0) :
  Math.min(relativeStart, len);

// Steps 9-10.
var end = arguments[2];
var relativeEnd = end === undefined ?
  len : end >> 0;

// Step 11.
var final = relativeEnd < 0 ?
  Math.max(len + relativeEnd, 0) :
  Math.min(relativeEnd, len);

// Step 12.
while (k < final) {
  O[k] = value;
  k++;
}

// Step 13.
return O;
```

and I can't find any necessity to assign O as Object(this).

Is it written just for readability or is there any specific reason for assigning?

Comment: Well, it only follows the steps of the algorithm in the spec. And there it says: `Let O be ? ToObject(this value).` http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.fill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments on the code, this section is to accurately pollyfill the first steps documented in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.fill).

> 1. Let O be ToObject(this value).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(O).

Though a bit out-of-order, this is performing the fucntion of `ToObject(this value)`:

```
var O = Object(this);
```

Basically, if it is called on a non-object, the non-object should be cast to an `Object`.

For example, if we were to run this bit of mostly-nonsensical code in a JavaScript engine which natively supports this method, we would see a `Number` object instance gets returned.

```
Array.prototype.fill.call(123);
```

That line would ensure the same result from the polyfill.

Comment: I got it! I almost use strict mode, so I doubt its purpose. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The Object constructor returns its argument when the argument is already an object. If it's not an object, it returns the "objectified" version of the argument: a String instance if it's a string, a Number instance if it's a number, etc.

The function in question is a little weird, and in particular the value of `this` will *usually* be an object anyway. It doesn't *have* to be, but you kind-of have to go out of your way to get to the innards of the polyfill with a `this` value that isn't an object.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `this` is always an object in non-strict mode, but can be a primitive in strict mode.

Comment: @FelixKling yes good point. I'm trying to figure out what that code is trying to do; in particular I don't see the point of those right-shifts by 0. Nothing checks for `.length` being there, so if the function is applied to the wrong type of object it'll fail in a fairly clumsy way. But yes what you suggest is true.

Comment: I guess it just tries to be very close to the spec.

Comment: @FelixKling ah OK. But that really doesn't make a lot of sense, because what happens with intermediate values in the conceptual "machine" implied by the spec isn't the same as what happens statement by statement in actual JavaScript code.

Comment: Thank you guys! Answers and conversations help me a lot!